# qemu spice: fails to use ipv4 and always fallback to socket

Tags: qemu

- qemu: 8.1.3 (and ui-spice-app, ui-spice-core)
- spice 0.15.2-1
- spice-protocol 0.14.4-1

I have a strange issue, qemu keeps ignoring my ipv4 parameters and always falls back on unix socket:

If I even try from CLI with the most basic invocation, it fails:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -display spice-app -spice ipv4=on,addr=10.0.0.10,port=12345 ..
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: Spice: ../spice-0.15.2/server/reds.cpp:2551:reds_init_socket: getaddrinfo(/tmp/.4447F2/spice.sock,12345): Temporary failure in name resolution
```

same for localhost or with a clean profile/user account

As you can see in the getaddrinfo function, it tries to resolve an address with a file path, ignoring the value in the **addr** variable.

it is pretty new issue, I always used the same invocation, this is what I used in my scripts (versioned btw).

I don't understand. It does that on two different OS (Arch/Ubuntu) with the relative same version 8.1.

I don't use libvirtd usually, but even with libvirtd and the right config in qemu.conf (discarding socket feature), it keeps falling back on socket.

Any idea, pls?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is related to the use of

```
-display spice-app -spice ...
```

I you want to setup to a spice endpoint over network in a headless mode, it must be declared as follow:

```
-display none -spice ipv4=on,addr=10.0.0.10,port=12345 ..
```